# Aws cognito add predefined users

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

I'm working on a react native project. And I'm new to AWS Cognito. I have completed the email/phone signup using AWS Cognito. now I easily signup or login with AWS Cognito. And My expectation is there any possibilities to add some predefined users. ex: if I add some users ex(user1@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com) in aws.That particular user only can signup/login into the app. other users(emails or phone) restricted to signup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this would be through the cognito-idp cli. The command [admin-create-user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-create-user.html) will create a test user.

Here is an example:

```
$ aws cognito-idp sign-up \
  --region YOUR_COGNITO_REGION \
  --client-id YOUR_COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID \
  --username admin@example.com \
  --password Passw0rd!
```

Once your user is created, you also need to confim sign up, if this is enabled in your user pool.

```
$ aws cognito-idp admin-confirm-sign-up \
  --region YOUR_COGNITO_REGION \
  --user-pool-id YOUR_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID \
  --username admin@example.com
```